# Running Jest tests across multiple runners?

Tags: jestjs, gitlab

I'm wondering if anyone knows of an example or an easy way to implement Jest running parallel across multiple servers.

We have thousands of tests and it's getting pretty slow and tiresome to keep upgrading our EC2 type.

Wondering if there's a way to spread the load.

I could implement our own... but I'm trying to be a lazy developer.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on jestjs (I don't use it personally so can't say). If you're able to run a subset of the tests, you could then separate the load across multiple jobs. Multiple jobs in the same stage can run concurrently if you have enough runners available.

As a dumb example, if you could do something like:
`run tests 1-1000` in one job,
`run tests 1001-2000` in another, etc. then they can run in parallel. If you upload the test report after they finish, make sure to give them separate names so they don't collide/cause confusion.

An example `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  ...

build:
 # don't care at the moment

test_set_1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - # run tests 1-1000
  artifacts:
    path: /path/to/test/report
    name: "First Test Report"

test_set_2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - # run tests 1001-2000
  artifacts:
    path: /path/to/test/report
    name: "Second Test Report
```